# SQL results for all rows between two dates

Tags: c#, sql, date, between

I'm stuck with a SQL query.

I have a situation like this: in the `bookings` table. I have two simple `DATETIME` columns `date_start` and `date_end`, and I have two datepickers where the user can select those two dates and values from them we should call `dp_date_start` and `dp_date_end`.

Rows in the result set need to fit into following criteria:

- if `date_start` and `date_end` are completely inside that range
- if only `date_start` or `date_end` are in that range
- if `date_start` or `date_end` are border values

Basically it's a booking logic, imagine it that's a room that cannot be booked if it's already occupied.

What I have tried so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM bookings 
WHERE 'dp_date_start' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date 
   OR 'dp_date_end' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date 
   OR start_date BETWEEN 'dp_date_start' AND 'dp_date_end' 
   OR end_date BETWEEN 'dp_date_start' AND 'dp_date_end';
```

But if fails if i.e. `'dp_date_start'` is equal to `end_date`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  In addition, the single quotes mean your query is invalid SQL and should generate an error.

Comment: I know, look at it as a pseudo-code, since I'm using this in C#. It doesn't need to be 100% syntax valid, I just need the logic. And btw single quotes are ok in C# in SQL :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two start dates and two end dates. You can check if both start dates are between both the period as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM bookings 
WHERE dp_date_start between start_date AND end_date 
   OR start_date BETWEEN dp_date_start and dp_date_end
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I'm getting proper results in PhpMyAdmin in improvised model of that table. I will test it tonight since I don't have that project with me atm.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice explanation to fix your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/325964/1500601. Explains the logic well to find such overlaps.

You can modify your query according to this logic. Probably the implementation would be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE dp_date_start <= end_date AND start_date >= dp_date_end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Provided link helped me with possible solution. It's slightly different than your suggestion:

`SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE dp_date_start <= end_date AND dp_date_end >= start_date`

This is getting me correct results in improvised table. I will test it tonight on real project and let you know.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Please let me know if you had to change the query. Glad that the  explanation was helpful.

Comment: Something was wrong with these queries so I have ended up with Popeye's query. Maybe it was something to do with T-SQL tables (used in C#).